Ubuntu 20.04 occasionally fails to open zedmini camera?
There are video0 and video1 under /dev, but they cannot be opened and prompt that they cannot be found. This camera works normally on Windows systems. Another brand's monocular camera can be used, but this one is not.
This camera is not always unusable on Ubuntu 20.04, it can be used occasionally, but I don't know the reason.
When I open the guvcview software, an error message "Guvcview error no video device found" pops up.

 $ lsusb -d 2b03: -v

Bus 004 Device 006: ID 2b03:f682 Technologies, Inc. ZED-M
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               3.00
  bDeviceClass          239 Miscellaneous Device
  bDeviceSubClass         2
  bDeviceProtocol         1 Interface Association
  bMaxPacketSize0         9
  idVendor           0x2b03
  idProduct          0xf682
  bcdDevice            1.00
  iManufacturer           1
  iProduct                2
  iSerial                 0
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x0150
    bNumInterfaces          2
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              512mA
    Interface Association:
      bLength                 8
      bDescriptorType        11
      bFirstInterface         0
      bInterfaceCount         2
      bFunctionClass         14 Video
      bFunctionSubClass       3 Video Interface Collection
      bFunctionProtocol       0
      iFunction               2
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass        14 Video
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Video Control
      bInterfaceProtocol      0
      iInterface              2
      VideoControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                13
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      1 (HEADER)
        bcdUVC               1.10
        wTotalLength       0x004f
        dwClockFrequency      150.000000MHz
        bInCollection           1
        baInterfaceNr( 0)       1
      VideoControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                18
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      2 (INPUT_TERMINAL)
        bTerminalID             1
        wTerminalType      0x0201 Camera Sensor
        bAssocTerminal          0
        iTerminal               0
        wObjectiveFocalLengthMin      0
        wObjectiveFocalLengthMax      0
        wOcularFocalLength            0
        bControlSize                  3
        bmControls           0x00000000
      VideoControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      3 (OUTPUT_TERMINAL)
        bTerminalID             2
        wTerminalType      0x0101 USB Streaming
        bAssocTerminal          0
        bSourceID               4
        iTerminal               0
      VideoControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                13
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      5 (PROCESSING_UNIT)
        bUnitID                 3
        bSourceID               1
        wMaxMultiplier          0
        bControlSize            3
        bmControls     0x00003eff
          Brightness
          Contrast
          Hue
          Saturation
          Sharpness
          Gamma
          White Balance Temperature
          White Balance Component
          Gain
          Power Line Frequency
          Hue, Auto
          White Balance Temperature, Auto
          White Balance Component, Auto
        iProcessing             2
        bmVideoStandards     0x00
      VideoControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                26
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      6 (EXTENSION_UNIT)
        bUnitID                 4
        guidExtensionCode         {2ccb0bda-6331-4fdb-850e-79054dbd5671}
        bNumControl             2
        bNrPins                 1
        baSourceID( 0)          3
        bControlSize            1
        bmControls( 0)       0x03
        iExtension              2
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x86  EP 6 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               9
        bMaxBurst               0
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass        14 Video
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Video Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol      0
      iInterface              0
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                            14
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                  1 (INPUT_HEADER)
        bNumFormats                         1
        wTotalLength                   0x00bf
        bEndPointAddress                  129
        bmInfo                              0
        bTerminalLink                       2
        bStillCaptureMethod                 0
        bTriggerSupport                     0
        bTriggerUsage                       0
        bControlSize                        1
        bmaControls( 0)                     0
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                            27
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                  4 (FORMAT_UNCOMPRESSED)
        bFormatIndex                        1
        bNumFrameDescriptors                4
        guidFormat                            {32595559-0000-0010-8000-00aa00389b71}
        bBitsPerPixel                      16
        bDefaultFrameIndex                  1
        bAspectRatioX                       0
        bAspectRatioY                       0
        bmInterlaceFlags                 0x00
          Interlaced stream or variable: No
          Fields per frame: 2 fields
          Field 1 first: No
          Field pattern: Field 1 only
        bCopyProtect                        0
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                            38
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                  5 (FRAME_UNCOMPRESSED)
        bFrameIndex                         1
        bmCapabilities                   0x00
          Still image unsupported
        wWidth                           2560
        wHeight                           720
        dwMinBitRate                442368000
        dwMaxBitRate                1769472000
        dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize     3686400
        dwDefaultFrameInterval         166666
        bFrameIntervalType                  3
        dwFrameInterval( 0)            166666
        dwFrameInterval( 1)            333333
        dwFrameInterval( 2)            666666
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                            42
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                  5 (FRAME_UNCOMPRESSED)
        bFrameIndex                         2
        bmCapabilities                   0x00
          Still image unsupported
        wWidth                           1344
        wHeight                           376
        dwMinBitRate                121282560
        dwMaxBitRate                808550400
        dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize     1010688
        dwDefaultFrameInterval         100000
        bFrameIntervalType                  4
        dwFrameInterval( 0)            100000
        dwFrameInterval( 1)            166666
        dwFrameInterval( 2)            333333
        dwFrameInterval( 3)            666666
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                            34
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                  5 (FRAME_UNCOMPRESSED)
        bFrameIndex                         3
        bmCapabilities                   0x00
          Still image unsupported
        wWidth                           3840
        wHeight                          1080
        dwMinBitRate                995328000
        dwMaxBitRate                1990656000
        dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize     8294400
        dwDefaultFrameInterval         333333
        bFrameIntervalType                  2
        dwFrameInterval( 0)            333333
        dwFrameInterval( 1)            666666
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                            30
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                  5 (FRAME_UNCOMPRESSED)
        bFrameIndex                         4
        bmCapabilities                   0x00
          Still image unsupported
        wWidth                           4416
        wHeight                          1242
        dwMinBitRate                1316321280
        dwMaxBitRate                1316321280
        dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize    10969344
        dwDefaultFrameInterval         666666
        bFrameIntervalType                  1
        dwFrameInterval( 0)            666666
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                             6
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                 13 (COLORFORMAT)
        bColorPrimaries                     1 (BT.709,sRGB)
        bTransferCharacteristics            1 (BT.709)
        bMatrixCoefficients                 4 (SMPTE 170M (BT.601))
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0400  1x 1024 bytes
        bInterval               0
        bMaxBurst              15

Bus 003 Device 002: ID 2b03:f681 STEREOLABS ZED-M Hid Device
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0
  bDeviceSubClass         0
  bDeviceProtocol         0
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x2b03
  idProduct          0xf681
  bcdDevice            2.05
  iManufacturer           1 STEREOLABS
  iProduct                2 ZED-M Hid Device
  iSerial                 3 15071845
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x0022
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0
    bmAttributes         0xe0
      Self Powered
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower              100mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Boot Interface Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      2 Mouse
      iInterface              0
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.11
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength      47
         Report Descriptors:
           ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               1
can't get device qualifier: Resource temporarily unavailable
can't get debug descriptor: Resource temporarily unavailable
Device Status:     0x0001
  Self Powered


Ubuntu 20.04 is quite old and may not work with recent hardware. Can you try 24.04 in a live USB and test if the camera works there?

@ArchismanPanigrahi I use Ubuntu 22.04 and Ubuntu 24.10, and the situation is the same.
